# Unable to start unicorn on port 80 using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn

`cap production unicorn:start` fails with the following error, trying to start my rails app on port 80.

```
F, [2013-06-14T04:33:51.420113 #13986] FATAL -- : error adding listener addr=0.0.0.0:80
/home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:147:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno::EACCES)
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:147:in `new'
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:147:in `bind_listen'
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:229:in `listen'
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:773:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:773:in `each'
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:773:in `bind_new_listeners!'
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:141:in `start'
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
from /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

set use_sudo true returns the following error

```
* executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' rm -rf /home/ec2-user/apps/bdr_prod/releases/20130517085418"
servers: ["64.433.69.129"]
[ec2-user@64.433.69.129] executing command
*** [err :: ec2-user@64.433.69.129] sudo
*** [err :: ec2-user@64.433.69.129] :
*** [err :: ec2-user@64.433.69.129] sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
*** [err :: ec2-user@64.433.69.129] 
command finished in 1542ms
```

Comment: Are you starting with `sudo`?

Comment: I am deploying via capistrano and not doing this manually. rvmsudo is the solution, not sure how to do it via cap

Comment: Wouldn't you want a web server (nginx, apache) running on port 80 and forward to another port or a socket for unicorn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had issues with this before, and had to add this to my `deploy.rb`:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Answer (score 1):

To run ssh sudo command in remote server, disable 'require tty' in remote server

**Run:**

`~$ sudo visudo`

**Edit:**  /etc/sudoers

> # Disable "ssh hostname sudo ", because it will show the
>   password in clear.
>
> # You have to run "ssh -t hostname sudo ".
>
> # comment require tty
>
> **# Defaults    requiretty**

**Reference:** http://www.lansweeper.com/kb/39/TTY-Required-error-during-linux-scanning.html