# Rails App on Port 80 on Amazon EC2 - Use Nginx or IpTables

Tags: amazon-ec2, unicorn

I have a simple rails app set up on EC2 and I run it with Unicorn. I want to set it up now so that it runs on port 80. Using the -p flag with the unicorn_rails command did not work; I received an error saying permission denied:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-164-110-7 current]$ unicorn_rails -p 80
F, [2013-08-02T04:41:41.441613 #3297] FATAL -- : error adding listener addr=0.0.0.0:80
/home/ec2-user/uc_social_server/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:147:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/ec2-user/uc_social_server/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:147:in `new'
    from /home/ec2-user/uc_social_server/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:147:in `bind_listen'
```

Searching for solutions online, I keep finding posts about setting up Nginx + Unicorn. Then there are some mentions of using IpTables to redirect port 8080 traffic to port 80.

I am not sure which approach to take.

Do I need Nginx?

Is there a way ec2-user can be allowed to run the unicorn process on port 80?

Is the IpTables solution a good approach? I somehow don't think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here they apparently solved the problem you have with `unicorn -p`:

[Unable to start unicorn on port 80 using capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101219/unable-to-start-unicorn-on-port-80-using-capistrano)

The other two solutions are also both going to work well.

With IPtables you can redirect the incoming traffic from port 80 to your unicorn socket listening on 8080 and back. That's happening on the TCP layer.

The nginx approach is a transparent proxy setup. All magic is happening on the HTTP layer which gives you the advantage of being able to manipulate requests and responses, set up caching etc. nginx is a lovely tool which probably beats unicorns possibilities by far (and won't really slow you down while)

Comment: I tried `unicorn -p`, same error. My collaborator on the app feels we do not need Nginx as of now. I will go try the IpTables solution to redirect port 80 traffic to port 8080.

Comment: I ended up using IpTables. Thanks for your help.